# Upgrading new Mac Mini to SSD

Tags: macos, mac, hard-drive, ssd

Brand new MAC user. I started it, runs slow, I already knew I'm going to upgrade to SSD.

Model: A1347

After reading some documentation I was under impression that system have "BIOS" which will allow me to connect to wifi and install OS on a brand new drive:
http://support.apple.com/kb/HT4718

So, I replaced hard drive with SSD one and now when I turn system on all I see is gray screen. Within 30 seconds or so I get flashing folder icon with question mark inside.

Should I do something? Like enter BIOS? I thought it's going to be easy

Answer (score 1):

EDIT: see Topic Starter's comment below!

---

The website you refer to is mentioning how you can do a fresh install form a recovery partition. On your brand new hard drive, there is no recovery partition.

The easiest way to install OSX on a new hard drive is by creating a bootable flash drive with the Max OSX setup on it.

You can learn how to do that here: http://www.macworld.com/article/1161069/make_a_bootable_lion_installer.html

Comment: OP here. Obviously you wrong. With Mountain Lion you can. What I didn't do right - I was pressing Cmnd-Optn-O-F instead of Cmnd-R. I had to repartition drive and now OS being downloaded from internet..

Comment: If the Mac is (or has been updated firmware to) capable of Internet Recovery, then CMD+R, after not finding local recovery to boot from, will automatically attempt an Internet Recovery. You can also directly boot to Internet Recovery by CMD+OPT+R or CMD+OPT+SHIFT+R to bypass looking for local recovery.

Answer (score 1):

I was able to figure it out. My problem was that I was trying to access BIOS via Cmnd-Optn-O-F and this failed. When I used Cmnd-R - Recovery tool started.

I had to first create partition on my new disk and then choose "Install from internet"
It's working now, however I don't get one thing... HOW DID IT KNOW MY WIFI credentials??

When I started MAC first time I did connect via WiFi and created account. Then I removed HDD and installed SSD(brand new) instead.

So, I guess MAC writes something on internal flash drive??

[image]

Comment: Unless you clear NVRAM, Mac should remember the last WiFi network it had connected to.

Answer (score 0):

Apple already has a [support article specifically for the flashing ? folder](https://support.apple.com/en-us/102601).

If this is a 2010 Mac Mini and has at least [Firmware 1.5](https://support.apple.com/kb/dl1479) to support Internet Recovery, or 2011 or newer Mac Mini which already supports Internet Recovery then CMD+R, after not finding local recovery to boot from, will automatically attempt an Internet Recovery.

More granularly, from https://support.apple.com/en-us/HT204904:

- **CMD+R**: When you press and hold these two keys at startup, macOS Recovery will offer the **current version of the most recently installed macOS**. *(Recovery on local disk - Currently installed MacOS)*
- **CMD+OPT+R**: When you press and hold these three keys at startup, macOS Recovery might offer the **latest macOS that is compatible with your Mac**. *(from internet - newest MacOS for this Mac)*
- **CMD+OPT+SHIFT+R**: When you press and hold these four keys at startup, macOS Recovery might offer the **macOS that came with your Mac**, or the closest version still available. *(from internet - Oldest MacOS for this Mac)*